# Filter accepts 1 inch fitting supply is 3/4

Tags: plumbing, water-pressure, water-filtration, flow-rate

I am installing a whole house filter and UV system. The connections are all 1 inch. My incoming main (city) is also 1 inch, but has been reduced to 3/4 pex (feeding a softener). I plan to put the filter before the softener, so should I run 1 inch (vs 3/4) from the main, into the filter/UV system and then reduce to 3/4 for the softener? Or is keeping the whole setup at 3/4 ok?  I’m thinking I should run 1 inch all the way to softener because I can and because I will have slower velocity which I am learning is better for filtration/UV. Am I correct?

Comment: Note that the velocity of the water in the pipe won't affect the velocity of the water inside the filter. It will affect the pressure loss due to ppe friction (dynamic head) and on that basis I'd stay with 1" as long as possible, up to and including considering replacing the softener if it cannot support 1" connections.

Answer (score 2):

I would put the filter at the softner and do the reduction there. I would suspect you have line(s) feeding outside faucets that should be connected before the filter. I do not know what filter you have so I will also suggest adding shut off valves both in front and behind the filter so you can isolate it when it is time to change/clean the filter element.

Comment: I would suggest adding valves before and after _every_ water appliance to ease maintenance/replacement.